# What metric does pgrouting use to calculate distances?

Tags: distance, geopy, pgrouting, great-circle

I was comparing distances between points using **pgrouting** and comparing it with Vincenty and great circle distances computed using **geopy**, but I'm finding that the min distance between two points is lower bounded by the **pgrouting** distances. This makes no sense because the "straight" (as the crow flies) distance between two points should be the min distance.[image]

How is pgrouting computing the "cost" between two points?

I'm sure I can find this by digging through the source code, but I'm not sure how to find my way around, and it could be faster to ask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PgRouting doesn't calculate distances. It takes a 'cost' field for each edge and adds up the cost for each edge in a path. You need to figure out what cost value you're passing to PgRouting and get that straight. Maybe you measured on a different unit or projection.